# Selecting features from an expression

Tags: qgis, query, definition-query, query-layer

I am having problem creating a query. I have a data map, which is organised in areas with codes (which in turn correspond to funding oportunities). I am trying to select for each code a layer. Up until then, its pretty straight forward.

The problem arises when I want to combine two codes. Through the Attribute Table, I select features using a expression,from the FIELDS AND VALUES, for example

```
"BINDUNG" LIKE '%11Z%'
```

However when I try to use

`"BINDUNG" Like '%11Z%' AND LIKE '%812%'`

or

```
"BINDUNG" Like '%11Z%' AND NOT LIKE '%812%'
```

it simply doesn´t work.

Is there another expression I can use?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot simply chain the operators ('LIKE'), you need to repeat the field relation ("BINDUNG"):

---

Also I need to add: if you want to select features having one of both attributes you need to use the `OR` operator. The `AND` operator combines both expression into one condition so that only those features would be selected whose attributes match both expressions combined.

```
"BINDUNG" LIKE '%11Z%' OR "BINDUNG" LIKE '%812%'
```

would select features with either matching `%11Z%` or `%812%`.

```
"BINDUNG" LIKE '%11Z%' OR "BINDUNG" NOT LIKE '%812%'
```

would select features with matching `%11Z%` and those not matching `%812%`.

```
"BINDUNG" LIKE '%11Z%' AND "BINDUNG" NOT LIKE '%812%'
```

would select features matching `%11Z%` and not `%812%` at the same time (e.g. `00011Z000` would work, `00011Z000812000` would not).

---

<s>Also, I think you can use</s>

```
"BINDUNG" IN ('%11Z%', '%812%')
```

in the first case alternatively, but I'm not 100% sure if the `%` wildcard is valid for `IN`. Try it if you want.
 No. `IN` requires exact matching (e.g. `"BINDUNG IN ('00011Z000', '000812000')`).